# SMT solvers or an alternative for uninterpreted symbols + ∀

Tags: z3, smt, theorem-proving, formal-verification, formal-methods

I wanted to use Z3 to prove theorems from axioms with universal quantifiers, but Z3 seems to be a bad fit for my problem. It is able to solve some such problems, but it seems to get stuck every now and then. **If not Z3, what other tools can I look to?**

To give you an idea of the type of problem, I want to prove
`∀….Pₙ`
from the axioms/assumptions
`{∀….P₁, …, ∀….Pₘ}`.
All symbols are uninterpreted and all formulas have only universal quantifiers.

I know about proof assistants, but I need a fully automatic decision procedure. While FOL is not decidable, is there a chance that there is a decision procedure for the fragment I'm interested in, either in some other tool, or perhaps, even in Z3?

Answer (score 2):

These sorts of questions come up often, alas SMT solvers are just not a good match with quantifier heavy problems. The best you have is specifying patterns (See [E-matching based quantifier instantiation](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-e-matching-based-quantifier-instantiation) for details). But it is quite fragile and definitely not that terribly easy to use.

Your best bet, against what you wanted, is to use proof assistants; and hope that their automated tactics (such as [sledgehammer](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2009-1/sledgehammer.html) of Isabelle) can discharge the proofs without the need for much user intervention.

This is, of course, general advice without actually knowing anything about your specific problem. If you post a concrete instance of it, you might get a better answer in terms of if there might be another way to model it using z3.

Answer (score 0):

Given the current formulation of your fragment, you're still in an undecidable fragment of FOL. If you could restrict what your P are allowed to talk about then you might end up in a decidable fragment (e.g. monadic, guarded, effectively propositional, there are a few).

Besides SMT solvers and proof assistants, there is a whole class of automated theorem provers that are refutationally complete for such problems (i.e. if there is a proof of inconsistency they will eventually find it), which SMT solvers are not. [CASC](https://www.tptp.org/CASC/) is a good place to find out about such solvers as it's a compeittion focussing on these kinds of problems. [Vampire](https://vprover.github.io/) is a very good example (note, I am a developer of Vampire).